# First run of query on big table takes very long after server restart

Tags: sql, sql-server

After a server restart when I run the following query it takes a very long time. The table has 1.500.000 rows and the query returns 140.000 rows.

```
select 
Oid, -- Primary Key 
IsTranslated -- bool(bit) column
from Translation
where [Language] = '24648b4e-05ac-42cb-b6cf-c1167b6a41b7'
```

There is an index on the Language column. The first run after server restart takes 6 minutes to complete, the subsequent queries take 1-2 seconds to complete. Adding "WITH(INDEX(iLanguage_Translation))" to the FROM part of the query did not improve performance.

But the follownig query takes only 2 seconds to complete on the first run after a server restart:

```
select Oid -- Primary Key
from Translation
where [Language] = '24648b4e-05ac-42cb-b6cf-c1167b6a41b7'
```

The only difference between the two queries is an extra bool(bit) column. Why the transfer of 140.000 rows of an extra bit column takes 6 minutes?

I have SQL Server 2014 with an i7 2700K processor and 16GB of memory.

Here is the table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Translation](
    [Oid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [PropertyName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DefaultLanguageValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TranslatedValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsTranslated] [bit] NULL,
    [NodePath] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Language] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [OptimisticLockField] [int] NULL,
    [GCRecord] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Translation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Oid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/****** Object:  Index [iGCRecord_Translation]    Script Date: 2016.07.21. 12:09:08 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iGCRecord_Translation] ON [dbo].[Translation]
(
    [GCRecord] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [iLanguage_Translation]    Script Date: 2016.07.21. 12:09:08 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iLanguage_Translation] ON [dbo].[Translation]
(
    [Language] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Translation]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Translation_Language] FOREIGN KEY([Language])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Language] ([Oid])
NOT FOR REPLICATION 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Translation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Translation_Language]
GO
```

The final query that will be used in my web app uses all the columns of the table:

```
SELECT [Oid]
      ,[PropertyName]
      ,[DefaultLanguageValue]
      ,[TranslatedValue]
      ,[IsTranslated]
      ,[NodePath]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Language]
      ,[OptimisticLockField]
      ,[GCRecord]
  FROM [dbo].[Translation]
  where [Language] = '24648b4e-05ac-42cb-b6cf-c1167b6a41b7'
```

Execution plan:

[image: Execution plan]

Execution plan XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="12.0.4459.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="171288" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="102.045" StatementText="SELECT [Oid],[PropertyName],[DefaultLanguageValue],[TranslatedValue],[IsTranslated],[NodePath],[Description],[Language],[OptimisticLockField],[GCRecord] FROM [dbo].[Translation] WHERE [Language]=@1" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x7722D3C37A4ACDF4" QueryPlanHash="0xEBAED5C218B1FD8D" RetrievedFromCache="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="475" CompileCPU="2" CompileMemory="184">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="209425" EstimatedPagesCached="104712" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="4" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="20181" EstimateCPU="2.07874" EstimateIO="99.9661" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="171288" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="102.045" TableCardinality="1889620">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Oid" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="PropertyName" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="DefaultLanguageValue" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="TranslatedValue" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="IsTranslated" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="NodePath" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Description" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Language" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="OptimisticLockField" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="GCRecord" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="144003" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Oid" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="PropertyName" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="DefaultLanguageValue" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="TranslatedValue" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="IsTranslated" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="NodePath" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Description" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Language" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="OptimisticLockField" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="GCRecord" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Index="[PK_Translation]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                <Predicate>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[vintocon.archifm.Loc].[dbo].[Translation].[Language]={guid'24648B4E-05AC-42CB-B6CF-C1167B6A41B7'}">
                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[vintocon.archifm.Loc]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Translation]" Column="Language" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Const ConstValue="{guid'24648B4E-05AC-42CB-B6CF-C1167B6A41B7'}" />
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </Predicate>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="'24648b4e-05ac-42cb-b6cf-c1167b6a41b7'" ParameterRuntimeValue="'24648b4e-05ac-42cb-b6cf-c1167b6a41b7'" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: I suppose it's about cache. Try `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` instead of restarting - should have same effect.

Comment: I too would guess it is the buffer pool filling up for the first time the pages are used. Given that you have 1.5m rows saved in a clustered index where the clustering key is a GUID I would guess the index is very fragmented, which would explain why it takes a long time to read all the pages into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Read about `KeyLookup` operation on execution plan and create a covered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [iLanguage_Translation]
    ON [dbo].[Translation] ([Language]) INCLUDE (IsTranslated)
```

Comment: The problem is that in my final query I need all of the columns in the select, and varchar(max) columns can't be used as index

Comment: In your question I can't see any final queries... Please update your question and provide actual executions plans

Comment: Updated the question